# My First Rebus!

Tags: rebus

```
 D
 R
 A 
EGDEH
 G
 E
 D
```

Try solving the Rebus puzzle above, according to me its neither too hard nor too easy!

Comment: Oh, I just saw it and its already answered.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nice idea!  Nice puzzle!
(It is easy to solve, since there is so much openly visibile information)

The answer is

> Dragged through a hedge backwards

Comment: Thanks... I'll try making harder ones next time! :)
Btw... correct answer